# How to delete shared preference throughout whole application

Tags: android

So I made a basic app. It consists of 3 activities; A, B and C. A is the main screen there is a button 'new Game' in which it leads to B and another button 'continue' which leads to C. In B, the user can choose their difficulty and based on whatever the user clicked on, C will execute. If the user goes back to A and presses on the continue button, C will load along with the saved sharedpreference.

I am creating the shared preference in my C class first. When `onPause()` is called, I create the shared preference by:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("brainData", MODE_PRIVATE); 
SharedPreferences.Editor editBrainData = pref.edit();
```

and put the required variables inside it. And on my `onStart()` method, I load the variables by getting `SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("brainData", MODE_PRIVATE);` and using pref.getInt, pref.getBoolean etc. I am not sure whether these are good places to save and load onto the shared preference files.

Now I am having problems here. Whenever the user finishes and the score is outputted, I want the user to go to A whilst deleting the sharedpreference data. Ive tried:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("brainData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
pref.edit().clear().commit();
```

but that doesn't seem to delete it because after finishing the game, when I go back to A and press continue, it still loads the variables to the absolute last played point in time.

Comment: Have you verified that all the accesses to you preferences are being called in the order that you expect?  In other words, have you done logging or step-through debugging to make sure everything is called?